# how to convert int to uint8 in java

Tags: java, matlab, int, type-conversion

I write an image filter in Matlab and I want to translate it to java in order to use my android application. How can I convert short or int to uint8 data format.

BTW:I know there is no type like uint8 in java.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Matlab:**

```
for iX = 1:imageX
    for iY = 1:imageY
        x(1:3) = input(iX,iY,:);
        output(iX, iY, :) = uint8(p1.*x.^5 + p2.*x.^4 + p3.*x.^3 + p4.*x.^2 + p5.*x + p6);
    end
end
```

**Java:**

```
for (int iX = 0; iX < width; iX++) {
            for (int iY = 0; iY < height; iY++) {
                Arrays.fill(x, bitmap.getPixel(iX, iY));
                short total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    total +=p1[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 5) + p2[i]
                            * Math.pow(x[i], 4) + p3[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 3)
                            + p4[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 2) + p5[i] * x[i] + p6[i];
                }
                output.setPixel(iX, iY, total);
            }
        }
```

Comment: 8 bit int in java is byte

Comment: Your current java implementation doesn't work?

Comment: @thang but it's signed. So it may cause troubles.

Comment: unfortunately, the value of total in java is different from matlab.

Comment: @thang No! No! No! No! 8bit int in Java is signed!

Comment: In matlab x is an representation of rgb color where - array of 3 elements where each element 1 byte?

Comment: Is `setPixel` last argument rgb color represented by java `int`?

Comment: i know byte is signed.  that's why i said 8 bit int, not 8 bit uint.  but you can work around that issue.  signed-ness is a bit representation.  what you would do is compute in short (or int or whatever) and then convert to byte for storing.

Comment: the reason why your java implementation outputs different values is not because of uint8 or anything.  it's because you're using vector operations in matlab (i assume for rgb components), and you're summing everything up in java in a single short.  they're different computations.

Comment: setPixel color parameter type is int but my math function should return uint8...

Comment: your math function should return 3 ints.  you can then jam the 3 ints into 3-bytes of the int that setPixel takes.  what is the type of output?

Comment: Performancewise this method is terrible.

Comment: i think he's just trying to get it to work first... which apparently it currently isn't.

Comment: output is Bitmap and I know the performance issue but after accomplishing this task I will optimize... My main idea is to learn how to use uint8 like structure in java :)

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz in matlab you don't use uint8. You are using array that later you convert to array of uint8. Do same in java. Use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create `total`. In matlab you handle each color component separately. Do same in java:

```
for (int iX = 0; iX < width; iX++) {
        for (int iY = 0; iY < height; iY++) {
            Arrays.fill(x, bitmap.getPixel(iX, iY));
            // Result color components.
            int[] res = new int[3];
            short total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                res[i] = p1[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 5) + p2[i]
                        * Math.pow(x[i], 4) + p3[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 3)
                        + p4[i] * Math.pow(x[i], 2) + p5[i] * x[i] + p6[i];
                // Make sure final value is in range [0, 255]
                res[i] = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, res[i]));
            }
            output.setPixel(iX, iY, Color.rgb(res[0], res[1], res[2]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a longer type in Java, for example, `short`<->`uint8`, `int`<->`uint16`, `long`<->`uint32`.

Or just use `int` for all those unsigned types under 32 bits and `long` for 32 bits:

When you operate on it, do `&` op in the end:

```
int i = 256 & 0xff;                             //uint8
int i = 65536 & 0xffff;                         //uint16
long i = (long) Math.pow(2, 32) & 0xffffffff;   //uint32;
// And So on
```

There is a "bit waste" as it always uses half of the type length. But in most cases, it won't be a serious problem.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expects arg[0] to be uint8 but int32 is provided  it does not work when trying to do it in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate limitation of java. This is what I would do.

1. Don't worry about the size, use an char or int
2. Write you own addition wrapper for `byte` using a bit mask to check the sign. This will be slow so I would go with #1. An alternative to this is to cast to a different data-type during the operation. Such as using an int before serializing the truncated version to a byte data-type.
3. See [Is there a Java library for unsigned number type wrappers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193031/is-there-a-java-library-for-unsigned-number-type-wrappers)

Comment: Could you give an example  please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193031/is-there-a-java-library-for-unsigned-number-type-wrappers

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will make an transformation for you:

```
int value = 115;
byte transformed = (byte) value;
// value == transformed => true
```

Warning: In case of transforming int to a byte you risk loosing 3 * 8 bits of information:

```
int value2 = 357;
byte transformed2 = (byte) value2;
// value2 == transformed2 => false
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no unsigned data type in java so u will have to go with one out of them

```
int,char,short,byte.
```

These all are signed data type in java but keep in mind the type conversion rules while u assign the value of one data type value to another.