# Convert typedef byte U8 to object oriented Java class by extending Byte

Tags: java

I want to convert:

```
typedef byte   U8;
```

to OO like this:

```
public final class U8 extends Byte    { 
      U8( byte x  ){
          super(x); 
      } 
};
```

This results in an error "The type U8 cannot subclass final class byte".

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is there an easy way to subclass a final class? No.

Comment: You can not extends final class.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. *Is there a simple way to do this?* - A simple way to do *what* exactly? Extend a final class (by definition this can't be done)? Create a class that wraps `byte` similar to the `Byte` class?

Comment: byte is final class therefore we cant extends final class

Comment: Ermm ... I think you mean `Byte` not `byte`.   (You cannot have a >>class<< with the name `byte` ... because it is a Java reserved word.)

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do this would be to reuse someone else's library.  There are some leads in this Q&A:

- [Is there a Java library for unsigned number type wrappers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193031/is-there-a-java-library-for-unsigned-number-type-wrappers)

What you are actually trying to do (extend `java.lang.Byte`) is both impossible (because the `Byte` class is `final`) and conceptually wrong.  The sets of numbers represented by an unsigned byte and a signed byte are different.  Therefore neither is conceptually a subtype of the other.  If you model one as a Java subclass of the other, you will end up with type anomalies and runtime value checking to avoid them.

---

Finally, while this kind of modeling gives you a nice OO program, the downside is that you will take a significant performance hit relative to using primitive types and "tweaking" to deal with signed versus non-signed.  You might be interested to know that there is a new API in Java 8 for doing unsigned operations on signed primitive types.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/unsigned_api
- [How to use the unsigned integer in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556017/how-to-use-the-unsigned-integer-in-java-8)

The API consists of new `static` methods in the existing wrapper classes.

Comment: Thank you all for yore answers.
I took from the package org.joou the Ubyte but I am working in processing.org.
I get the error "No enclosing instance is available due to sume intermediate constructor invocation" on all constructors.
Can you help?

Comment: Bot without seeing your code.  Ask a new Question with an MCVE included.