# java - Why is 0x000F stored as unsigned?

Tags: java, unsigned

I was reading through examples trying to understand how to convert signed bytes to unsigned integer counter parts.

The most popular method that I have come across is:

```
a & 0xFF
```

Where `a` is the signed byte.

**My question** is why is 0xFF stored as unsigned? Are all hex values stored as unsigned? If so why?

And how does "and"-ing turn off the sign bit in the sign integer?

It would be great if someone could break down the process step by step.

Comment: so original data type of `a` is `int` ?

Comment: Where did you learn this method? It will convert 12345 (a perfectly fine non-negative `int`) into 57. Is this what you want?

Comment: `0xFF` is a signed integer. It's just happens to be non-negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably saw this in code that converted a byte to an integer, where they wanted to treat the byte as an unsigned value in the range 0-255. It does not apply to integers in general. If you want to make an integer `a` "unsigned", you can do:

```
int unsignedA = a & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

This will ensure that `unsignedA` is positive - but it does that by chopping off the high bit, so for example if `a` was -1, then unsignedA is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

There is no way to turn a 32-bit signed Java integer into a 32-bit unsigned Java integer because there is no datatype in Java for a 32-bit unsigned integer. The only unsigned integral datatype in Java is 16 bits long: `char`.

If you want to store a 32-bit unsigned integral value in Java, you need to store it in a `long`:

```
long unsignedA = a & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I have edited my question. I understood better from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3388321/5826291

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Erwin's answer about converting a byte to an integer: In Java, `byte` is a signed integer type.  That means it has values in the range -128 to 127.  If you say:

```
byte a;
int b;
a = -64;
b = a;
```

The language will preserve the value; that is, it will set `b` to -64.

But if you really want to convert your byte to a value from 0 to 255 (which I guess you call the "unsigned counterpart" of the byte value), you can use `a & 0xFF`.  Here's what happens:

Java does not do arithmetic directly on `byte` or `short` types.  So when it sees `a & 0xFF`, it converts both sides to an `int`.  The hex value of `a`, which is a byte, looks like

```
a      =       C0
```

When it's converted to a 32-bit integer, the value (-64) has to be preserved, so that means the 32-bit integer has to have 1 bits in the upper 24 bits.  Thus:

```
a      =       C0
(int)a = FFFFFFC0
```

But then you "and" it with `0xFF`:

```
a      =       C0
(int)a = FFFFFFC0
       & 000000FF
         --------
a & FF = 000000C0
```

And the result is an integer in the range 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, literals (1, 0x2A, etc) are positive unless you explicitly indicate that they are negative. It's how we intuitively write numbers.

This previous question answers you question about converting to unsigned. [Understanding Java unsigned numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388204/understanding-java-unsigned-numbers)